# In C# Cake How to Read a Text File into List<string>?

Tags: c#, build, devops, continuous-deployment, cakebuild

Given a carriage return delimited text file say of folder names, how do I read this file into List in the Cake build system for C#?

When I try to use the File class, it complains that File(string) is a method, which is not valid given the context:

```
filePath filePath;
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath FullPath);
```

How would I write this so it works with Cake?

https://cakebuild.net/

Comment: Does it work if you fully quality the type? `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()`?

Comment: Or if you specifically want a `List<string>`, then does [`System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath).ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-7.0) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cake has its own `File` class, so there's a namespace conflict where the compiler doesn't know which `File` class you want to use.

You have to fully-qualify the type name in your call, to include the `System.IO` namespace:

```
filePath filePath;
string fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath FullPath);
```

You might also be interested in the [Cake.FileHelpers](https://cakebuild.net/extensions/cake-filehelpers/) addin which adds a set of aliases for Cake to help with simple file operations such as Reading, Writing and Replacing text.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines) or [`File.ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines).

Neither of these returns a `List<string>`, but both create objects that work with `foreach` loops and Linq extensions, including `.ToList()` if you need it.

I also see this:

> When I try to use the File class, it complains that File(string) is a method, which is not valid given the context:

There are two possibilities here. One is, in addition to `System.IO.File`, you either have another `File` type or a `File` method in the same scope. If this is the issue, then remove any `using System.IO` directive you may have at the top of the code file and fully-qualify any use of `System.IO.File`.

The second possibility relates to the code snippet, with the repeating `filePath filePath` or `filePath fullPath` on both lines. Neither really makes sense at all, and indicates there might be a lack of understanding for basic syntax.

Comment: Can you address the statement "When I try to use the File class, it complains that File(string) is a method"?

Comment: Sounds like they made their own `File` class, so now there's a naming collision between their class and `System.IO.File`

Comment: See the answer to this question. There's a namespace conflict with File. So File needs to be fully qualified.